# create edge list in python from a general edge list

Tags: python, csv, graph-theory

I have a csv where each row is a document. The first value in each row is the ID. All subsequent values (after the first value) in each row are documents that are cited in the document.

For example, in my csv, let's assume I have four documents (so four rows):

```
A, B, D, E, G, H
B, C, E
C, I, K, L
D, A, C, H, I
```

So for document 1 (A), this document cites five other documents (B, D, E, G, H).

I want to create an edge list (and export into a new csv) such that:

```
A, B
A, D
A, E
A, G
A, H
B, C
B, E
C, I
C, K
C, L
D, A
D, C
D, H
D, I
```

How can I create the new edge list csv file using python?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you should at least try something before posting on SO. if you wanna know where to start, https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html is a good place to begin.

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv
from itertools import product
with open('file.csv') as f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for k, m in [(t, s) for i, *j in spamreader for t, s in product(i, j)]:
        print (k, m)
```

whose result would be:

```
A  B
A  D
A  E
A  G
A  H
B  C
B  E
C  I
C  K
C  L
D  A
D  C
D  H
D  I
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a couple for loops

```
l = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H'],
    ['B', 'C', 'E'],
    ['C', 'I', 'K', 'L'],
    ['D', 'A', 'C', 'H', 'I']]
edge = []            
for i in l:
    for j in i[1:]:
        edge.append([i[0],j])
for i in edge:
    print i
```

Or even easier just use list comprehensions

```
l = [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H'],
    ['B', 'C', 'E'],
    ['C', 'I', 'K', 'L'],
    ['D', 'A', 'C', 'H', 'I']]   

edge = [[i[0],j] for i in l for j in i[1:]]

for i in edge:
    print i

['A', 'B']
['A', 'D']
['A', 'E']
['A', 'G']
['A', 'H']
['B', 'C']
['B', 'E']
['C', 'I']
['C', 'K']
['C', 'L']
['D', 'A']
['D', 'C']
['D', 'H']
['D', 'I']
```